# Putting javascript variable into xsl attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xslt

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  var i=0;

  function increase()
  {
  i++;
  document.getElementById('slide').innerHTML= +i;
  document.getElementById('slidenum').innerHTML = document.getElementById('slide').innerHTML;
  }
</script>

<p>
 slide: <slide id="slide">0</slide>
</p>
<xsl:variable name="slidenum">
  <slidenum id="slidenum">0</slidenum>
</xsl:variable>
<p>
<xsl:variable name="imgsrcs">
  <xsl:value-of select="//movie[@num='($slide)']/thumb_img"/> </xsl:variable>
```

Here I have a function to increment slide by 1 every onclick for the forward button.
I want to put the slide id into the imgsrcs variable where it says $slide so onclick of the forward button it will go to the next movie if this is possible I don't know much css or javascript but a place to look to learn how I can do this to basically make a slideshow would help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your XSLT runs outside of the browser:

JavaScript runs when the page is displayed in the browser, while your XSLT is generating HTML before the browser even loads it (on the server side). So there is no way for JavaScript to have any impact on XSL variables.

What you can do is to transform your XML movie data into a JavaScript dictionary, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var thumbs = { 
<xsl:foreach select="//movie">
    "<xsl:value-of select="@num"/>": "<xsl:value-of select="thumb_img"/>",
</xsl:foreach>
};
</script>
```

and then update your HTML using something like:

```
var img=document.getElementById("...");
img.url = thumbs[$slide];
```

The code is not tested, just to give you an idea how you can do that.

Please note that you have to check whether your data needs to be escaped when generating JavaScript from XML (f.e. make sure there are no quotes in the XML data).